# Add new libraries to compile anyterm. How to edit Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, inih

I'm modifying Anyterm (http://anyterm.org/) to add a configuration file that I need in some changes that I made.

I'm using inih project (https://github.com/benhoyt/inih) to read that file. This file contents my database data to connect to it.
Also I include mysql libraries and everything is ok with them in compile time.

The problem comes when I'm trying to add the new inih libraries to the Makefile. Inih's files have the extension .c and .cpp, however anyterm's files have the extension .cc

The Makefile is this:

```
default_target: anytermd

SRC_DIR=../src

VPATH=${SRC_DIR} .

UNAME_S=$(shell uname -s)

ifeq (${UNAME_S},Darwin)
else
HAVE_GNU_LD=1
endif

LIBPBE_DIR=../libpbe

CPP_FLAGS=

GCC_FLAGS=-pthread
#GCC_FLAGS=-D_REENTRANT

COMPILE_FLAGS=$(CPP_FLAGS) $(GCC_FLAGS) -W -Wall ${OPTIMISE_FLAGS} ${DEBUG_FLAGS}

CC_COMPILE_FLAGS=$(COMPILE_FLAGS)

LINK_FLAGS=${GCC_FLAGS} ${DEBUG_FLAGS} \
        -lutil

ifeq (${UNAME_S},OpenBSD)
LINK_FLAGS+=-liconv
endif

ifeq (${UNAME_S},Darwin)
LINK_FLAGS+=-liconv
endif

LIBPBE_MAKE_OPTIONS=
include ../libpbe.mk

CC_SRCS=$(sort $(notdir $(wildcard ${SRC_DIR}/*.cc)) static_content.cc)

BLOBFILES=anyterm.html anyterm.js anyterm.css copy.png paste.png copy.gif paste.gif

BLOBS=$(addsuffix .blob.o,$(BLOBFILES))

OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(notdir $(basename $(CC_SRCS))))

%.o: %.cc
        $(CXX) $(CC_COMPILE_FLAGS) -c $<

ifdef HAVE_GNU_LD
%.blob.o: ../browser/%
        cp $^ . ; $(LD) -r -b binary -o $@ $* ; rm $*

else
%.blob.c: ../browser/% ./mk_blob

        ./mk_blob $(subst .,_,$*) < $< > $@

mk_blob: mk_blob.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $<
endif


anytermd: $(OBJS) $(BLOBS) $(LIBPBE_LIB)
        $(CXX) -o $@ -I/usr/include/mysql  -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC   -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX $(OBJS) -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lssl -lcrypto $(BLOBS) $(LINK_FLAGS)

%.d: %.cc
    $(CXX) -MM -MG -MT $@ -MT $(<:%.cc=%.o) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(GCC_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

DEPENDS=$(addsuffix .d,$(basename $(OBJS)))

-include $(DEPENDS)

install: FORCE
    install anytermd /usr/local/bin

clean: FORCE
    $(RM) -f *.o *.blob.c static_content.cc

veryclean: clean
        $(RM) *.d

.PHONY: default_target install FORCE


static_content.cc: ../scripts/mk_static_content.sh ../browser/*
        PATH="$${PATH}:../scripts" ../scripts/mk_static_content.sh $(BLOBFILES) > $@

static_content.o: CPP_FLAGS+=-I../src
```

The inih's files are in src directory and when I try to do "make" I receive these errors:

```
Anyterm.o: In function `checkPermission(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, booking_info&)':
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x4527): undefined reference to `INIReader::INIReader(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x4596): undefined reference to `INIReader::ParseError() const'
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x46a7): undefined reference to `INIReader::Get(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const'
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x4894): undefined reference to `INIReader::Get(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const'
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x49e2): undefined reference to `INIReader::Get(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const'
Anyterm.cc:(.text+0x4af5): undefined reference to `INIReader::Get(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const'
```

Which leads me to believe that inih's libraries are missing in the linker.
What have I to change in Makefile to compile anyterm with inih?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made these changes to Makefile and works for me:

```
CPP_FLAGS=-I$(SRC_DIR)
...
FILTER=mk_blob.c
CC_SRCS=$(sort $(notdir $(wildcard ${SRC_DIR}/*.cc)) static_content.cc)
CC_SRCS+=$(sort $(filter-out ${FILTER},$(notdir $(wildcard ${SRC_DIR}/*.c))))
CC_SRCS+=$(sort $(notdir $(wildcard ${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp)))
...
%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $(CC_COMPILE_FLAGS) -c $<

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CC_COMPILE_FLAGS) -c $<
```

Thanks to all for the help.